# hpgl file not working to print on pen plotter

Tags: python

I am using a vintage pen plotter that only reads `hpgl` files,  there is a specific way in which to put pen up/pen down formatting for the plotter to read.
Anyone that knows anything about pen plotting please help!

Here is my code

```
x = 50
y = 50
clear()

while True:
    xrand3=random.uniform(600,700)
    yrand3=rand.uniform(0,800)
    penUp.chiplotle.hpgl.PD([(xrand3,yrand3)])
    myfile.write(penUp.format)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,(100,0,0),(xrand3,yrand3),(xrand3,yrand3),1)
    penDown=chiplotle.hpgl.PD([(xrand3,yrand3)])

pygame.dispay.flip() 
input(pygame.event.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here.

Does the plotter work with Chiplotle? Usually, getting the cable and serial comms correct is the hardest part. If you send this text to the plotter:

```
IN;SP1;PU400,400;PD;PA4400,400,4400,4400,400,4400,400,400;PU;SP0;
```

does it draw an appx 10 cm square? (You can try it without a pen; plotters usually work without them.)

Chiplotle's [tutorial](http://music.columbia.edu/cmc/chiplotle/manual/chapters/tutorial/intro.html) shows you how to drive a plotter from a Python program. It needs some commands you're not using.